# Issue with observeEvent in Shiny Module Used Across Different Tabs

Tags: r, shiny

I'm facing a challenge with my Shiny application. I have designed a UI with two tabs, each tab has its own reset button. The idea is to use a Shiny module to handle the server logic for these buttons. However, I am encountering a problem where clicking the reset button triggers no response.

Below is a simplified snippet of my code:

```
library(shiny)

# UI for Reset Button
reinitButtonUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  actionButton(ns("ReinitData"), "Reset", class = "btn-lg btn-secondary")
}

# Server logic for Reset Button
reinitButtonServer <- function(input, output, session, mode_transport) {
  ns <- session$ns

  observeEvent(input[[ns("ReinitData")]], {
    print(paste("Reset button clicked for transport mode:", mode_transport))
    reinit_data(mode_transport)
  })
}

reinit_data <- function(mode_transport) {
  print(paste("Function reinitialiser_donnees called for transport mode:", mode_transport))
}

# Main UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Land",
             reinitButtonUI("landModule")
    ),
    tabPanel("Helicopter",
             reinitButtonUI("helicopterModule")
    )
  )
)

# Main Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(reinitButtonServer, "landModule", mode_transport = "land")
  callModule(reinitButtonServer, "helicopterModule", mode_transport = "helicopter")

  print("Server function loaded.")
}

# Run the App
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I’ve included some print statements to track the flow, but upon clicking the reset button, nothing gets printed to the console, indicating the observeEvent isn't being triggered.

I believe my module logic should allow for a differentiation between the tabs, and have the respective reset button react accordingly. However, it's not working as expected.

Any insights on what might be going wrong, or suggestions on how to get the observeEvent to trigger upon clicking the reset button would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing the input values of a module, you don't need to use `ns` - if you change `input[[ns("ReinitData")]]` to `input$ReinitData` you'll find it works as you expect.